# Resize event not working with div resize:both

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i got a resizeable div:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="resize:both">
something here
</div>
```

I need to catch event when user resize this window.

Both

```
$("#mydiv").resize(function() {
        alert('works'); 
    });
```

and

```
$("#mydiv").bind('resize', function(){
        alert('works'); 
    });
```

dont work ;/

Answer (score 1):

[the resize event](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) is actually triggered only when the window changes sizes, not when a specific element resizes.

If you want to create an event on a specific element when it is re-sized, I've used [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) in the past; works well.

You can also just do something like this:

```
$.fn.changeSize = function(fn){
var $this = this,
    w0 = $this.width(),
            pause = false; // this is only necessary if you don't want the callback to overlap
$this.sizeTO = setInterval(function(){
         if (!pause){
    var w1 = $this.width();
    if (w1 != w0) { 
        pause = true
        w0 = w1;
        fn(function(){pause=false;}); // if you don't want the callback to overlap, have the callback accept another callback to resume the check.
    }
         }
}, 100);
}
```

this checks the element every .1 seconds. if the height has changed, then it will call the `fn` callback.

Comment: Watch out. The callback fn will be called many times wihtin a short period... not so  good.

Comment: I've not had a problem with that but I made some edits to ensure the callback execution doesn't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

please try to use this code:

```
(function() {
    function myfunction(){
       // do what you need to do in the event
    }

    $(window).on("resize", myfunction);
    $(document).on("ready", myfunction);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for all cases with divs (ref: https://web.dev/resize-observer/)

```
var ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    const cr = entry.contentRect;
    console.log('Element:', entry.target);
    console.log(`Element size: ${cr.width}px x ${cr.height}px`);
    console.log(`Element padding: ${cr.top}px ; ${cr.left}px`);
  }
});

// Observe one or multiple elements
ro.observe(someElement); // replace someElement with your element var
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery ui to resize the div:

```
$("#mydiv").resizable();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/DWAdh/)

If you want to do something on window resize you need something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  alert("DO SOMETHING");
});
```

And [check this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) too, I think that will help you!